# Django admin site - how to override adding manytomanyfield with + sign?

Tags: django, django-admin, many-to-many

When clicking + sign in admin site, to add new ManyToMany field, a popup appears, and it asks you to fill out the fields to the ManyToMany'ed table. I have a schema like below:

```
class RelTypes(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class People(models.Model):
    code = models.CharField(max_length="15", unique=True)
    rel_types = models.ManyToManyField('RelationTypes')
```

I want to display the `code`, which user enters when adding a new field to People model (in admin site), in the popup, right before the textbox of the name field of RelTypes. How can I achieve it? Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
# models.py
from django.db import models

class RelationType(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class People(models.Model):
    code = models.CharField(max_length=15, unique=True)
    rel_types = models.ManyToManyField('RelationType')

# admin.py
from django.contrib.admin.options import ModelAdmin

class RelationTypeAdmin(ModelAdmin):
    class Media:
        js = ('admin/related_type_change_form.js',)

# related_type_change_form.js
;(function($) {
    if(window.opener) {
        $(function() {
            $('#content-main').prepend('<p id="code_value"></p>');
            var target_el = $("#code_value");
            var code_el = window.opener.$("#id_code");
            var update_code = function() {
                target_el.text(code_el.val());
            }
            code_el.on('keyup change', update_code);
            update_code();
        });
    }
})(django.jQuery);
```

Comment: Better names would be: People=Person, rel_types=relation_types.